# Extend Observable and set external source

Tags: rxjs

I want to extend Observable and set another source (e.g. another Behaviour Subject)

E.g. NgRx is doing it here:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/9.0.0/modules/store/src/store.ts#L20

But RxJS Observable gives a deprecation warning on ´Observable.source´: https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.5.5/src/internal/Observable.ts#L25

This code is using the deprecated ´Observable.source´ - and it works:

```
const source: BehaviorSubject<any> = new BehaviorSubject(1);

class ObsStore extends Observable<any> {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.source = source; // Observable.source is deprecated
    }

    // Implement custom methods here
    customMethod1() {}
}

export const obsStore$ = new ObsStore();
obsStore$.subscribe(data => console.log('output', data));

source.next(2);

// output 1
// output 2
```

Still I wonder if it is safe to use `source`. Is there maybe an alternative way to set an external source for an Observable?

NgRx also implements the lift method:
https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/9.0.0/modules/store/src/store.ts#L90-L95
Not sure if that is needed.

Here is a stackblitz example:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/extend-observable

Note: I want to extend Observable and add some custom public methods to it. The Custom Observable should behave like an BehaviorSubject but it should not expose `next` or `getValue`. Actually only `pipe` and the custom methods should be public.

Comment: can you provide more class use cases, maybe most of the time all you need is to create or pass in source in constructor, instead of extending it.

Comment: what about `class ObsStore extends BehaviorSubject<any> {`?

Comment: I'd say it's safe to do things this way. [NgRx follows the same approach](https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/master/modules/store/src/store.ts#L20).

Comment: @Fan Cheung The Custom Observable should have an API which is similar to NgRx Store (https://github.com/ngrx/platform/blob/9.0.0/modules/store/src/store.ts). It is a class which extends Observable and adds some other methods like `dispatch`, `select`...
I want to be able to use the `pipe` method on the instance of the Custom Observable.

Comment: @satanTime extending BehaviorSubject will expose methods like `getValue` or `next` on the Custom Observable. I just want to expose `pipe` from Observable and some own methods.

Comment: with the `source` property it's the same, you can do `obsStore$.source.getValue` or `next` etc.

Comment: if you want to hide methods you can do a middle class with `extends Subject...` and then a class for export like `export class ObsStore extends Omit<MiddleClass, 'getValue' | 'next'>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this tweet from Ben Lesh (RxJS):
https://twitter.com/BenLesh/status/1366787138898055169

"I strongly advise people not extend Observable (or really any type that they don't own, from any library)."

Also Alex Okrushko from the NgRx team thinks that NgRx should better not have extended Observable.
https://twitter.com/AlexOkrushko/status/1379028869789970432

Composition will work much better + future proof.